# Field within cavity of a conductor in electrostatic conditions

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

We know that the electric field inside a conductor is zero in electrostatic conditions. Now if we have a cavity in the conductor then too the field is zero within it. Can this result be thought of as: if our conductor had no cavity then the electric field was zero within it, now removing the metal and creating a cavity won't change anything thus field should remain zero.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the cavity does not contain any charges. In electrostatics, electric field can be expressed as a function of charge distribution $\rho$ only:
$$E = \int \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\rho \left ( r' \right )\left ( r - r' \right )}{\left | r - r' \right |^3}d V'$$
In this particular case the charge distribution will not change when the cavity is created in the conductor, so the electric field will remain zero. However, one has to be careful applying this reasoning more generally in case distributions of induced charges are altered.